# Asp.Net Panel control in MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, panel

Is it possible to use Panel control(Asp.net) with scrolling in MVC3 Razor? If not what will be the alternative for this control?

Comment: What about a simple HTML-Div?

Comment: Can we have scrolling in div?

Comment: [Yes](http://www.domedia.org/oveklykken/css-div-scroll.php)

Comment: What to do if i need only vertical scroll?

Comment: [overflow-x, overflow-y](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it as very simple one. Thanks Sternr. I used div instead of Panel

coding

CSS will be

```
{
width:180px;
height:584px;
background-color:#CCCCCC;   
float:left;
overflow:auto;
}
```

And if you don't need horizontal / vertical scroll specifically

You can give like

```
    overflow-x:Hidden; Or
    overflow-y:Hidden.
```

I didn't check compatibility for all browser versions. But it works fine on Chrome 13.0.782.107, Firefox 5.0 and  IE 9

For IE8:
 -ms-overflow-y: hidden;

Thanks